# bootstrap 3 modal header background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I have a `bootstrap` modal that I want to set its `background-color`:

[image]

But I get a white space on the top corners:

[image]

This is my style:

```
.modal.modal-alert .modal-dialog .modal-content {
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0;
}
.modal.modal-alert .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-header {
   padding:9px 15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #0480be;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
     border-top-left-radius: 6px;
     border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.modal.modal-alert .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.modal.modal-alert .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-footer {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

The border radius must be 6px and its what I have.

Here is the code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgGvoP

> Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `border-radius` on `.modal-header` to `3px`. Considering it is inside of `.modal-content`, same radius wouldn't match.

```css
.modal.modal-alert .modal-dialog .modal-content {
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0;
}
.modal.modal-alert .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-header {
  padding: 9px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: #0480be;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
.modal.modal-alert .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.modal.modal-alert .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-footer {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h3></h3>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Click to open Modal</a>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
<div class="modal modal-alert fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Modal Body</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Found a great work done by a person
His username is Oskar

Saved a lot of my time.
Please check this link,it can't be any better.

All we will need to do is add the following classes:

```
modal-header modal-header-primary
modal-header modal-header-default
modal-header modal-header-success
modal-header modal-header-warning
modal-header modal-header-danger
```

Here is the link - [Change background color of Modal-Header](http://www.bootply.com/s6x5oKLiDG)

Answer (score 1):

> `bg-success bg-primary bg-info bg-warning bg-danger`
>   use one of these class with 
>   `modal-header`

Answer (score 0):

`border-radius` for Parent element and modal box header was equal.

If you increasing the `border-radius` means it will shows the background color of `.modal-content` class of modal box.

So you have to increase the `border-radius` of `.modal-content` 3px larger than `modal-header`

Ex:

```
.modal.modal-alert .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-header {
padding: 9px 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
background-color: #0480be;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
border-top-left-radius: 6px;
border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

.modal.modal-alert .modal-dialog .modal-content {
border-radius: 9px;
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue I just added this CSS and fixed
margin-right: -1px;